# How to define custom POST operation in YAML?

Tags: symfony, routes, api-platform.com

In my [api-platform](https://api-platform.com/) project I want to create a custom `POST` operation. While this works well using annotations for the routing, I get stuck using YAML.

API resource definition

```
# src/AppBundle/Resources/config/api_resources/resources.yml
AppBundle\Entity\Foo:
    collectionOperations:
        get:
            method: 'GET'
        special:
            route_name: 'foo_special'
```

Routing

```
# app/config/routing.yml
foo_special:
    path: '/foo/special'
    methods:  ['POST']
    defaults:
        _api_resource_class: 'AppBundle\Entity\Foo'
        _api_collection_operation_name: 'special'
```

Error message:

> "hydra:description": "Unable to find the controller for path \"/foo/special\". The route is wrongly configured."

Any ideas what is wrong here?

Comment: There are no custom POST operations in YAML. Just like there are no such operations in ASCII or UTF-8. Interpretation of the meaning of the ASCII characters, even combined into YAML scalars is done by the application.

Comment: That is very helpful. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [meyerbaptiste on github](https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/issues/338#issuecomment-310318701):

> If you use the ADR pattern (`Action` class + `__invoke()` method), you have to define your controller (or your action here) as a service and then use the service name as controller. (i.e. `_controler: app.special_action` or `_controller: AppBundle\Action\Special`).
>
> You can use annotations too, see https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations#creating-custom-operations-and-controllers.

Answer (score 0):

```
defaults:
        _controller: 'AppBundle:Foo:special'
        _api_resource_class: 'AppBundle\Entity\Foo'
        _api_collection_operation_name: 'special'
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/350567) by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: a little explanation would be great.